# last message in conversation mysql Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to get the last message in MySQL using Laravel eloquent. I have tables

- **chats_users:** stores chat_id, user_id
- **chats_reply:** stores chat_id, sender_id, message, created_at

I tried the below code but it's not returning the last message.

```
    return $this->chat->join("chats_users", "chats_users.chat_id", "=", "chats.id")
                      ->join("chats_reply", "chats_reply.chat_id", "=", "chats.id")
                      ->where("chats_users.user_id", "=", $user_id)
                      ->take($limit)
                      ->skip($offset)
                      ->groupBy("chats_reply.chat_id")
                      ->get();
```

I also tried:

```
return \DB::select( \DB::raw("SELECT * FROM chats_reply msg inner join ( select max(created_at) created_at, message from chats_reply group by chat_id) m2 on msg.created_at = m2.created_at INNER JOIN chats_users mst ON mst.chat_id=msg.chat_id WHERE mst.user_id=$user_id") );
```

Comment: Do you get the expected results when you run the query by itself?

Comment: Have you tried orderBy() function in eloquent?

Comment: what does raw render

Comment: You use Raw if you want to query another in your database. For example if you want to get the count of 1 column. DB::raw('(Select count(table_you_want_to_count) from Database) as Count'). It's just an exaple

Comment: i mean what did his raw render

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? You said "last message in a conversation", yet you're filtering by user id, not chat id.

Comment: jedrzej.kurylo last conversation for that specific user. A user can be in multiple chats and i'm trying to return last message in each conversation that the user is part of

Comment: @Drew raw renders all the messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually worked.

```
\DB::select( \DB::raw(
            "SELECT * FROM chats_reply msg

             INNER JOIN ( 

                  SELECT max(created_at) created_at FROM chats_reply GROUP BY chat_id ORDER BY created_at

            ) m2 

            ON msg.created_at = m2.created_at
            "
     ) 
  );
```